# How to create a background only program that can show a window with text fields

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to create a program that consists of just a menu in the status bar (no dock icon or menu bar) that, when the user clicks on menu items, opens a window that allows the user to enter text (NSTextField and NSTextView).

I can make the program background only by setting the "Application is background only" property to YES in my Info.plist file, however, when I do this and display a window, firstly the window always appears behind other windows, and secondly I can't type any text into it (text goes to whatever last had focus - usually a source file in Xcode!)

This is definitely not something as simple as the fields are not enabled. Simply changing the "background only" property to NO fixes the issue, but then I get a dock icon and menu bar which I don't want.

Is what I'm trying to do possible or is there something about the background only mode that means my application can never receive text?

If it is possible what do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation for `LSBackgroundOnly`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-109268):

> You can use this key to create faceless background apps. You should also use this key if your app uses higher-level frameworks that connect to the window server, but are not intended to be visible to users.

So when they say “background only”, they mean background *only*.

The key you want is [`LSUIElement`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-108256). Xcode describes this as “Application is agent (UIElement)”.

I personally can't stand Xcode's default behavior of showing me descriptions of some of the keys' meanings. I recommend turning on “Show Raw Keys/Values”; then, Xcode will show you the real keys being used in the dictionary.